# Can someone explain the following code to me?

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

I am following along with the Rails 3 in Action book, and it is talking about override `to_s` in the model. The code is the following:

```
def to_s
  "#{email} (#{admin? ? "Admin" : "User"})"
end
```

I know that in Ruby you can display a value inside double quotes by the `"#{value}"`, but what's up with the double question marks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation). `"#{email} (#{admin? ? "Admin" : "User"})"` is equivalent to

```
email.to_s + " (" + (admin? ? "Admin" : "User") + ")"
```

that is

```
email.to_s + " (" + if admin? then "Admin" else "User" end + ")"
```

As a result of being enclosed in quotes, in this context `Admin` and `User` are used as strings and not as constants.

Comment: The `condition ? true_result : false_result` syntax is called [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) btw. You can find it most languages as a shorthand to `if ... then ... else`

Comment: Thanks! String interpolation is definitely something i'm going to read more on before continuing. Sounds like I should be more familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

The first question mark is attribute query methods in rails. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Attribute+query+methods

(provided you did not overwrite / redefine that method)

It is a shorthand method to see if that attribute present or not.

Answer (score 2):

Actually admin? is a function(probably defined somewhere in controller/helper method or model) that return boolean(true or false) and next question mark is just like a if condition

```
if admin? == true
 "Admin"
else
 "User"
```

first portion before ":" is for true case and other is for false case

Answer (score 2):

Don't see it as a double question mark, the first question mark is part of the method name (Ruby allows methods name to end with "!", "?", "=", "[]", etc). Since admin is a boolean value ActiveRecord add an admin? method that returns true if the user is an admin, false otherwise.

The other question mark is used with the colon (:) and you can see it like:

```
condition ? statement_1 : statement_2
```

If condition is true the first statement is executed, else the second one it evalueted.

So put these two things together and you have a string concatenation that add the "Admin" or "User" word between parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

This function is returning a string with the email and whether it they are an admin or user...
ie

```
user_1 = {:email => "test@email.com", :admin => true}
```

so the call

```
user_1.to_s
```

would return the string

```
"test@email.com Admin"
```